# Connection closed error while using VMware vSphere Management 5.5 SDK

Tags: c#, web-services, vmware, vsphere, vcenter

I have written a C# application to extract data from VMWare vCenter Server. When I run it on our production server I get the error:

```
The underlying connection was closed: A connection that was expected to be kept alive was closed by the server.

System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: A connection that was expected to be kept alive was closed by the server. ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.FixedSizeReader.ReadPacket(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.Net.Security._SslStream.StartFrameHeader(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security._SslStream.StartReading(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security._SslStream.ProcessRead(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.TlsStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.PooledStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.Connection.SyncRead(HttpWebRequest request, Boolean userRetrievedStream, Boolean probeRead)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebClientProtocol.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request)
   at Microsoft.Web.Services3.WebServicesClientProtocol.GetResponse(WebRequest request, IAsyncResult result)
   at Microsoft.Web.Services3.WebServicesClientProtocol.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
   at Vim25Api.VimService.RetrieveProperties(ManagedObjectReference _this, PropertyFilterSpec[] specSet)
   at vCenterTestConnect.vCenterESXHostInfo.getvCenterHostAdvancedInfo()
   at vCenterTestConnect.vCenterESXHostInfo.startExtraction()
```

The application works fine in the test environment (with 2 hosts and 20 VMs on vCenter Server). Any help to debug this error will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your VMWare server is closing the connection but without any reason, try to look at the server's log

Comment: I tried to look at the logs but could not find any useful information. Can you point exactly to what log file do I have to use to see the error. I exported System Logs from vCenter Server and looked at vpxd-xx.log

Comment: Error from vcenter logs is as below,   2016-01-13T11:54:18.979-05:00 [06464 error 'SoapAdapter.HTTPService.HttpConnection'] Failed to read header on stream <io_obj p:0x00000000414c5878, h:880, <TCP '127.0.0.1:8085'>, <TCP '127.0.0.1:53593'>>: class Vmacore::SystemException(An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine)